# no ssh outbound in an AWS Ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 Ubuntu instance A. Every time I run ssh user@someip from A command line I get "connection timeout" error. And I cannot find the auth log for user in server someip. To me it is apparent that instance A blocked the request.

```
ssh -v user@54.175.126.1XX
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 54.175.126.1XX[54.175.126.1XX] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 54.175.126.1XX port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 54.175.126.1XX port 22: Connection timed out
```

*sudo ufw status* returns 'inactive'

The security group for A allows ANY inbound and outbound traffic.

The ssh_config file:

```
Host *
SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

What else can I do?

**[added]** found this - everything works if I use the private ip of someip; however, connection timeout if i use the public ip of someip.
The 2 instances, A and someip, are in the same subnet.

Also, someip accepts ssh request from any ip and i can ssh from my PC.

**[added#2]** I cannot even ssh user@A-public-ip in server A.

Comment: I'd be looking at `someip`'s firewalls or security groups, not instance A.

Comment: @ceejayoz someip accepts ssh request from any ip and i can ssh from my PC

Comment: Warning: Accessing the other instance using its public IP will cause you to be billed for regional data transfer (when you get it working). Use the private IP for free data transfer bandwidth.